# Hacer un filtro en php/mysql

Tags: php

Para aquellos que no esta claro tema comparto el index y el template de mi pagina. Lo que me hace es la paginación. Quiero agregarle un filtro para que filtre esta paginación simplemente.
Index.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'database.php';
$database_connection = database_connect();
$title='hola';
$content='';
//user input
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$perPage = 2;
//Positioning
$start = ($page > 1) ? ($page * $perPage) - $perPage : 0;
$art = $database_connection->query("SELECT id FROM coffee");
//Query
$articles = $database_connection->prepare("SELECT id FROM coffee LIMIT $start,$perPage");

$articles->execute();
$articles = $articles->fetchAll();

$resultado = $database_connection->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM coffee");
$fila = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total = $fila["total"];
$pages = ceil($total/$perPage);

include 'Template_1.php';
?>
```

Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Stylesheet.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="banner">             
            </div>

            <nav id="navigation">
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tool.php">Coffee</a></li>
                    <li><a href="manager.php">Shop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div id="content_area">
                <?php

                require_once("tool.php");
                foreach ($articles as $article):
                    echo $article['id'];?>
                </br><?php
                endforeach;?></br><?php
                for($x=1;$x<=$pages;$x++):?>
                    <a href="tool.php?page=<?php echo $x;?>"><?php echo $x;?></a>
              <?php endfor;?>
                    </br>
                     <?php echo $content; ?>
            </div>

            <div id="sidebar">

            </div>

            <footer>
                <p>All rights reserved</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Pensaba que de la otra manera quedaría mejor pero bueno la re formulo a ver si alguien me da el soporte o me aconseja lo suficiente para llevar a cabo mi objetivo mil gracias.

Comment: Es simplemente que no tengo mucha idea sobre filtrados, se que deberia empezar por algun ejemplo antes de aplicarlo en mi pagina, espero sus consejos son bien recibidos, tambien lo unico que hace el filtrado es hacer una consulta entonces lo que querria es ver como quedaria actualizando articles cuando hago filtrado no se como implementarlo cualquier sugerencia o critica es bien recibida

Comment: Podría sugerir que lo intentaras con [tag:ajax], a mi parecer es mas sencillo ademas que el resultado es mejor a la vista del usuario, si gustas te dejo un ejemplo

Comment: si puedes me seria muy util

Comment: ¿que actualice `$articles` con qué valor? ¿cuál es el valor que estás obteniendo ahora? ¿cuál es el valor esperado?... Por otro lado, de todas las preguntas que hiciste, aún no has aceptado ninguna. Para aceptar una respuesta, debes hacer click en el ✓ a la izquierda de la misma (tanto tú como quien responde se benefician)

Answer (score 2):

Para hacer una petición [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax), personal mente la hago con [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) para eso importamos la librería, y hacemos el formulario donde se escribirán los datos a consultar:

```
<!-- importamos la libreria jquery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action="#?">
  <input type="text" name="buscar" id="buscar" value="Buscar">
  <input type="button" value="Buscar" id="botonBusqueda">
</form>
<!-- en este div se mostraran los resultados de las consultas -->
<div id="contenido"></div>
```

Creamos un evento `click` para que ejecute la funcion y le enviamos el valor que tiene el `input`:

```
<script>
// # = id, . = class
// usamos el id del boton para activar el evento cuando le den click en el
$("#botonBusqueda").click(function(){
  // capturamos lo que hay en el "input: text"
  var parametroBusqueda = $("#buscar").val();
  // enviamos el valor a la funcion
  filtro(parametroBusqueda);
});
</script>
```

creamos una función en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) donde ejecutamos el [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax):
**Nota :** esta función la puedes agregar en una pagina `.js` y agregarla a tu proyecto o bien insertarla en una etiqueta `<script></script>` donde tienes el formulario.

```
    function filtro(valueToSearch){
     // la consulta se la envío a la pagina PHP  
     var query = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE CONCAT(id) LIKE '%".valueToSearch."%'";
     $.ajax({
            // el tipo de envío que vamos a utilizar POST o GET
            type: 'POST',
            // colocamos la url donde se va a realizar la consulta 
            // ejemplo 
            // url: 'filtro.php', o bien url: 'controlador/filtro/filtro.php', donde este ubicado el archivo en tu proyecto
            url: 'url',
            // especificamos el tipo de envio puede ser json/html/xhtml entre otras
            dataType: 'html',
            // son los datos que enviaremos por POST o GET y que recibira la pagina PHP
            // data: "{}" dentro de los paréntesis especificamos los datos que enviaremos
            // "consulta:" el nombre con el que vamos a recibir el parametro en la pagina PHP ejemplo $_POST['consulta'];
            // "query" es el valor del parametro que vamos a enviar a la pagina PHP
            data: { consulta: query },
            // "beforeSend" esto se realiza mientras se ejecuta la consulta y retorna lo que necesitamos
            beforeSend: function(){
              // #contenido es el id del <div> donde vamos a mostrar el contenido
             $("#contenido").html("Realizando Busqueda");
            },
            // "success" se ejecuta cuando tenemos un resultado exitoso del ajax
            success:function(respuesta){
              // "respuesta" es lo que nos va a retornar la pagina PHP 
                $("#contenido").html(respuesta);
            },
            // "error" se ejecuta cuando algo fallo en la peticion
            error: function(){
               $("#contenido").html(" | error | ");
            }

        });
     }
```

pagina donde recibirá el parametro que estamos enviando desde [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) y realizas el proceso que deseas:

```
<?php
// pagina PHP donde recibimos el parametro que enviamos desde ajax
$resultado = $database_connection->query($_POST['consulta']);
// "$resultado" estaria el resultado de la consulta 
// y realizas lo demás que necesites la verdad no tengo muy claro que es lo que haces aqui creo que es un paginador o algo similar.
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$perPage = 2;
//Positioning
$start = ($page > 1) ? ($page * $perPage) - $perPage : 0;
$art = $database_connection->query("SELECT id FROM user");
//Query
$articles = $database_connection->prepare("SELECT id FROM user LIMIT $start,$perPage");

$articles->execute();
$articles = $articles->fetchAll();

$resultado = $database_connection->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM user");
$fila = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total = $fila["total"];
$pages = ceil($total/$perPage);

// con el "echo" retornas lo que deseas mostrar y quedara en la variable "respuesta" que declaramos en el "success" del ajax "success:function(respuesta)"
echo $retorna;
```

Espero lo entiendas intente ser muy especificó para que puedas hacerlo de la mejor manera, en realidad no hace mucho empece a experimentar con [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) y la verdad que me ha gustado bastante, recordemos que [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) es un framework de este lenguaje el cual resume algunas tareas de manera genial.

algunos enlaces que te pueden interesar

[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
[definición de stackOverFlow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/ajax/info)
[Libros web](http://librosweb.es/libro/ajax/)

Comment: hola esto es una delicia pero lo he intentado y cuando me hace echo $retorna me hace como un bucle interminable lo que hice fue coger la peticion ajax y la funcion etc. y poner en el html. Y en el php poner el codigo que me indicastes y me hace un bucle. Puede que este haciendo mal un saludo muchas gracias por su gran explicacion que es muy buena. gracias de nuevo

Comment: un bucle, que extraño no debería de ocurrir, puede que de pronto estes realizando un `include "pagina.php";` en la pagina `html` donde esta el formulario, es lo unico que se me ocurre. :S

Comment: es correcto una duda si no me reconoce retorna tengo que agregarla a una pagina js y despues agregarla al php? la puse dentro del script debajo de filtro(parametroBusqueda);
}); un saludo y gracias

Comment: la variable que declare como `$retorna;` es solo un ejemplo de lo que quieres enviar de vuelta o mostrar, no es necesario que lleve el mismo nombre. a lo que voy es que debes de mostrar en un `echo` lo que deseas que se muestre en el `<div id="contenido"> </div>` y no es necesario que agregues el `include` en el HTML

Comment: genial que te estes arriesgando, es algo confuso de inicio pero con el tiempo notaras que te ayudara a hacer todas las tareas de manera mas rapida y facil que solo con PHP, Animo!

Comment: hola intente hacerlo como tu para ver tu ejemplo y me aparece estos errores otice: Undefined index: consulta in C:\wamp\www\www\tool.php on line 6
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0006 132424 {main}( ) ...\tool.php:0

( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty' in C:\wamp\www\www\tool.php on line 6
( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty in C:\wamp\www\www\tool.php on line 6